# iOS 9 iPad multitasking - side-by-side multitasking without slide over

Tags: ios, ipad, ios9, multitasking

Is there a way to opt in to iOS 9 side-by-side multitasking without also opting into slide over?

The background is that our app UI copes fine in side-by-side, but doesn't really work at all in the narrow slide over mode. The app is mostly a PDF annotator, so the narrow slide-over mode doesn't really even make much sense from the point of view of the user experience.

I've been through the documentation/WWDC session and the only configuration possible seems to be using `UIRequiresFullScreen` which controls both side-by-side and slide-over at the same time.

Is there any way we can disable just slide over?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Seems like there's no way to do this without killing side-by-side. Obviously, the real UX challenge here is to find some way for the app to be useful in that narrow mode, but that's just the kind of gratuitous advice that overflows the stack here ;)

Comment: @Yar no, I've not found a solution yet. The only I can see would be to display a simple view controller in slide-over mode that just says something like 'Please open the window wider to use this app', but it's not really a good user experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two years on, I can confirm that this does simply seem to not be possible.

The only workaround I can see would be to display a simple view controller in slide-over mode that just says something like 'Please open the window wider to use this app', but it's not really a good user experience.

In the end we reworked our UI so it could do something workable in slideover mode.